# How do I block an ip address from seeing a group of webpages?

Tags: .htaccess

Using .htaccess I want to block 3 ip address from viewing any of the following pages:

```
http://url.com/foo
http://url.com/foo/bar
http://url.com/foo/bar/foo
```

So foo and anything after. How can I do this? All I can seem to find is how to block an ip address completely, but nothing to block it from viewing certain parts of a site. Also when they visit those pages, I want to show them a 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^111.111.111.111$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^222.222.222.222$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^333.333.333.333$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo/bar$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo/bar/foo$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [R=404,L]
```

This implements the conditions:

IF (A OR B OR C) AND (D OR E OR F) -> show 404 error

I made the urls match case insensitive just in case.

Comment: @Nadine Hm, worked for me. Can you eliminate %{REQUEST_URI} conditions and let me know, whether it worked? So we could break the problem into pieces.

Comment: I'll mark your answer as correct as I've got it working from your code. I had it in the wrong placein my .htaccess :) ty

Answer (score 1):

You only want to block the directory /foo/, so create an .htaccess file in /foo/ (which, intuitively, will only apply to /foo/). Then, use the same syntax to block IP addresses as usual:

```
order allow, deny
deny from 127.0.0.1
allow from all
```

I believe this returns a 403 - Forbidden. Not sure how you'd go about returning a 404. (You could just use the same page for 403 errors as you do for 404 errors, and it's unlikely the user will check the response status code)

**Edit:** does user4035's answer work if you begin with `RewriteEngine On`?

Comment: This won't work because the dir doesn't exists (the URL is rewritten).

Comment: You ought to add that to your question.